# Spring Data Rest error: Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property name found for type Project

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is my project entity:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name="project")
//@Data is bugged
@Getter
@Setter
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "project_name")
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String projectName;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "stage")
    private String stage;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            name="project_employee",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="project_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="employee_id")
    )
    private Set<Employee> employees;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "project")
    private Set<Ticket> tickets;

    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        if(employees == null) {
            employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        }
        employees.add(employee);
    }

}
```

This is my project repository where i try to implement a search query method:

```
import com.ghevi.bugtracker.entity.Project;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "projects", path = "projects")
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Long> {
    Page<Project> findByNameContaining(@RequestParam("projectName") String projectName, Pageable pageable);
}
```

This is the stack trace of the error: https://pastebin.com/7qzJNd25
(Got to use pastebin because of spam filter)

I dont understand since the project entity does have a projectName property.

Comment: Have you tried @Param("projectName')  instead of @RequestParam("projectName")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use exact same field name in method naming means `findByProjectNameContaining` as your field name is `projectName`

```
Page<Project> findByProjectNameContaining(@RequestParam("projectName") String projectName, Pageable pageable);
```